# Gauging expected membership length without new sign-ups overly affecting the value

Tags: statistics, usage-statistics

My question isn't language specific!

I'm trying to find a metric to help understand membership length of members of a site. Not surprisingly, if the site is very successful and many new people sign up, the actual account age average drops. The average also drops if many people cancel, although more slowly.

I've thought about using an offset, to only include people who signed up more than a year ago for example, but this creates a weird bias that ignores people who sign up and cancel within the year.

Another thought was to count only cancellations, but this could have perverted results in the case where 1000 members have been members for a decade and none have cancelled, but 10 users signed up and canceled the next day.

It seems un-intuitive to use the average, since a bulk of new sign-ups (a good thing) will be perceived as a bad thing in terms of average account length.

Any ideas for ways to measure 'expected' account age without having too much noise from new sign-ups?

Answer (score 2):

Why not actually measure account age, if that's what you want?

In pseudo-code:

```
def account-age(account):
  if account.current:
     return days(today() - signup_date)
  else:
     return days(cancel_date - signup_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - this is the most straight-forward approach, but the problem I have with it is that new sign-ups shift the average too low for it to be accurate. It's basically guaranteed in this circumstance that people won't sign up and cancel in the same day, so each new member makes the average come out lower.

Accurate in the sense of measuring 'expected account age on cancellation' as opposed to actual account age.